# dashboard for persistent volumes shows no data on AKS

Tags: prometheus-operator

Basically, I just installed a completely new prometheus-operator

```
helm install prometheus-operator prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -f values.yaml --namespace test
```

When I go to the dashboards, most of them are working as expected (I still have to figure out some things about the metrics, but that is not the problem here)

However, the dashboard "General / Kubernetes / Persistent Volumes" correctly proposes the namespaces and persistent volume claims as well as Free space and Used space, but I see N/A in the gauge on the right ...

What can be the cause of this ?

[image]

if this is of any help, I am using Azure Kubernernetes Services (AKS) ...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've finally understood the problem : there is not enough data on 7 days to make a gauge

if I wait 1 hour and change the time range to 1h, I can see the gauge